# Pushforwards of Riemmanian metrics and geodesics

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M_1,g_1)$ and $(M_2, g_2)$ be two Riemannian manifolds. Assume that $T : M_1 \to M_2$ is a diffeomorphism and $g_2$ is the pushforward of $g_1$ by $T$. Assume that $\gamma$ is a geodesic on $M_1$. Then, is $T \circ \gamma$ a geodesic on $M_2$?

Comment: Yes: By construction $T$ is an isometry, and tautologically isometries preserve all data determined by the metric, including geodesics.